# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present for POST request to GAS Web App

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet that I use to store data from a web page. As an experimentation, I created a chrome extension that scrapes the data from the page, and makes a POST request to GAS bound to my sheet. Handling the POST was easy, after I searched and found a snippet online:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAME");
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
  var col = 0;
  for (i in headers){
    if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){
      val = new Date();
    } else {
      val = e.parameter[headers[i]]; 
    }
    cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
    col++;
  }
}
```

I then deployed it as a web app with access: **Anyone, even anonymous**
Postman does the trick fine, and I indeed receive the data I want.
When my chrome extension does the POST however, I get the following error:
[Image from Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSF2I.png)

> Failed to load https:/script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxx/exec: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://random' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

From my limited understanding, I have to set the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` my GA script sends to the origin of the request, hence my extension.
How do I do that? Or if I'm mistaken, how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to look up [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) as there is a lot of issues regarding this as per [github post](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server/issues/154) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716430/how-to-fix-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-error).

Comment: I checked CORS and it's easy to do in a node server for example, but how do I set **response headers** in GAS?